# C# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 getCount()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
return query.OrderBy(e => e.Person.getCount(), sortDirection);
```

how can I rewrite this line ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use:

```
return query.ToList().OrderBy(e => e.Person.getCount(), sortDirection);
```

The case is EF tries to convert `getCount()` method to SQL. As it's custom method it can't be done so you should call `ToList()` to evaluate the expression and to make EF load objects from database to memory. Then linq can call you custom function to sort the data.

Comment: I think `AsEnumerable()` will be enough here, but +1